# How can I define a new prototype methods to arrays for count based the number passed to the method parameter?

Tags: javascript

I want to create the method for array prototype that counts in the array the value passed to the parameter of this method:

```js
Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, {
  countValues: function(numb) {
    return this.filter((value, index) => value === numb).length
  }
})

const newArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]

newArr.countValues(4) //Would return 2
```

Why doesn't the code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values passed to `Object.defineProperties` should be *property descriptors*, not just the plain values you want the prototype to be. In the property descriptor, you can define the `value` (as well as other descriptor options like if you want the property to be enumerable or writable):

```js
Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, {
  countValues: {
    value: function(numb) {
      return this.filter((value, index) => value === numb).length
    }
  }
})

const newArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]

console.log(newArr.countValues(4)) //Would return 2
```

In your original code, the value you give for `countValues` isn't a property descriptor, so it doesn't appear to do anything. (what it does is assign a non-configurable, non-writable property to `Array.prototype` whose value is `undefined`)

You can make the code slightly more efficient by using `reduce` instead of `.filter` and `.length`, thereby avoiding the creation of an intermediate array:

```js
Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, {
  countValues: {
    value: function(numb) {
      return this.reduce((a, b) => a + (b === numb), 0);
    }
  }
})

const newArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]

console.log(newArr.countValues(4)) //Would return 2
```

Since you're only defining one property, you could also consider using `Object.defineProperty`:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'countValues', {
  value(num) {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => a + (b === num), 0);
  }
});

const newArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]

console.log(newArr.countValues(4)) //Would return 2
```